# fs.writeFileSync function doesn't write to file when included as a module

Tags: node.js, fs

Consider the following:

`conversations.json` : `[]`

`db.js` :

```
let fs = require('fs');

let conversations = require('./conversations.json');

function addConversation(conversation){
    console.log(conversations);
    conversations.push(conversation);
    try{
        fs.writeFileSync('conversations.json', JSON.stringify(conversations));  
    }
    catch(err){
        console.error('Parse/WriteFile Error', err)
    }
}

module.exports = {
    addConversation
}
```

`app.js` :

```
let database = require('./db.js');

database.addConversation(
    {
        key1: '1233',
        key2: '433',
        key3: '33211'
    }
);
```

Running:
`node app.js`

No error is being raised. Everything compiled as expected. The problem is that the `conversations.json` isn't being updated once the `addConversation` function is called from `app.js`.

What's interesting is that once the `addConversation` is called within the `db.js` everything works great and the `conversations.json` is being updated.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I missing?

Probably when loading as a module, you're writing the file to the wrong directory.

When you do this:

```
fs.writeFileSync('conversations.json', JSON.stringify(conversations));
```

That writes `conversations.json` to the current working directory which may or may not be your module directory.  If you want it written to your module directory which is where this:

```
let conversations = require('./conversations.json');
```

will read it from, then you need to use `__dirname` to manufacture the appropriate path.

```
fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'conversations.json'), JSON.stringify(conversations));
```

`require()` automatically looks in the current module's directory when you use `./filename`, but `fs.writeFileSync()` uses the current working directory, not your module's directory.

Comment: I see, the __dirname constant basically creates an absolute path instead of a relative one that depends on the module loading file! Thank you so much! Great answer! Much appreciated mate!